# Mock different responses from @okta/jwt-verifier using jest

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, okta, ts-jest

I am using the @okta/jwt-verifier library to verify JWT's and I am trying to test this functionality by mocking the various responses from the library.

I can mock the `verifyAccessToken` method once for all tests however I am unsure exactly how to modify this mocked implementation to different tests i.e. the default will be a successful response returning a token however for some tests I need to mock the responses for a failed token verification i.e. an expired token.

This is what I have so far:

Implementation

```
const oktaJwtVerifier = new OktaJwtVerifier({
  issuer: "issuer domain",
});

export const verifyAccessToken = async (token: string) =>
  oktaJwtVerifier.verifyAccessToken(token, "audience");
```

Mock in tests

```
jest.mock("@okta/jwt-verifier", () => {
  return jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
    verifyAccessToken: () => ({
      foo: "bar",
    }),
  }));
});
```

This mock works as expected and when the code tested call the `verifyAccessToken` method the mocked implementation is returned.

However I would I return a different response for different tests in the same test suite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't pass the `factory` argument to `jest.mock()`, `jest.mock()` will mock
a module with an auto-mocked version. You can call `.mockResolvedValueOnce()` in each test case to provide different mock values later.

You can get the instance of the mocked `OktaJwtVerifier` class via [`mockFn.mock.instance`](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmockinstances)

> An array that contains all the object instances that have been instantiated from this mock function using `new`.

Handle the TS type for mocks using the `mocked` helper function of the `ts-jest` module. If you are using the latest Jest, use [`jest.mocked(source, options?)`](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api/#jestmockedsource-options) instead.

Note: I created a simple string as the resolved value for `verifyAccessToken()` method, **did not match** the real TS return type.

E.g.

`main.ts`:

```
import OktaJwtVerifier from '@okta/jwt-verifier';

const oktaJwtVerifier = new OktaJwtVerifier({
    issuer: "issuer domain",
});

export const verifyAccessToken = async (token: string) =>
    oktaJwtVerifier.verifyAccessToken(token, "audience");
```

`main.test.ts`:

```
import OktaJwtVerifier from '@okta/jwt-verifier';
import { verifyAccessToken } from './main';
import { mocked } from 'ts-jest';

jest.mock("@okta/jwt-verifier");

const OktaJwtVerifierMock = mocked(OktaJwtVerifier)

const oktaJwtVerifierInstance = mocked(OktaJwtVerifierMock.mock.instances[0]);

describe('76422353', () => {
    test('should pass 1', async () => {
        oktaJwtVerifierInstance.verifyAccessToken.mockResolvedValueOnce('a' as any);
        const actual = await verifyAccessToken('1');
        expect(actual).toBe('a');
    });

    test('should pass 2', async () => {
        oktaJwtVerifierInstance.verifyAccessToken.mockResolvedValueOnce('b' as any);
        const actual = await verifyAccessToken('2');
        expect(actual).toBe('b');
    });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/76422353/main.test.ts (15.361 s)
  76422353
    ✓ should pass 1 (2 ms)
    ✓ should pass 2

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        18.347 s
```

package versions:

```json
"@okta/jwt-verifier": "^3.0.1",
"jest": "^26.6.3",
"ts-jest": "^26.4.4",
```

Comment: This is working perfectly. makes a lot of sense now I have read it. Thank you.